# How should I handle calculated values for a large number of transactions stored in different places?

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, amazon-athena

Context:

I am building an application that takes income statements from external organizations and calculates client payout values using the rows in those statements. In order to calculate these payouts, the calculation needs to reference percentages in 2 other tables in my database in order to determine the result value. In addition, it is also possible for users to add their own transactions since sometimes income may come from alternative sources not included in those statements. It also allows users to include advance payments to their clients which they need to recoup. These additional transactions also need to be taken into account when calculating.

Because the statements can be very large, I decided to use AWS S3 to store them as CSV files and to use AWS Athena for analytics on these statements in the dashboard views. The transactions mentioned are in a table of their own called `transactions`.

Issue:

Since I need to show transactions that come from 2 different places, one being the statements stored in AWS S3 and the other being from the `transactions` table, I am having a hard time convincing myself that having to reference these two places to provide calculations for one conceptual thing, such as "transactions", is a good idea. However, I cannot think of another way of doing this that won't either cause my database to get huge very quickly or cause my monthly cost to skyrocket.

Months ago I decided that storing them all in the database table `transactions` was a bad idea since I think the performance hit would be immense. An individual statement can have tens or hundreds of thousands of rows. So, image multiple users needing to upload tons of statements per year. The database table will grow very large, very quickly.

Another issue is that in order to get the calculated transaction value, I need to take a percentage of the sum of all related values per statement and then take additional percentages (as fees) on top of that in order to show a true value of what the user must payout to their client and what money they need to recoup before that payout.

Question:

How should I handle going about calculating these values in a performant (and cost-effective) way given that they are stored separately (MySQL & S3) and rely on data from other tables in order to perform the calculations? Also, does this even seem like the best way to go about doing this? (I know that's opinion-based but I could use some educated opinions on this right now).

I have gone through a few different concepts and the one that I am up to now is the following:

1. Store transactions in `transactions` table.
2. Each time a statement is uploaded, add a reference row in the `transactions` table with the `statement_id` and a `0` transaction amount.
3. Upon querying the transactions, use AWS Athena Federated Query to query the data across my AWS RDS MySQL instance to get the data in the `transactions` table while also querying AWS S3 to get the data from the statements referenced from the `statement_id` column.
4. Use an AWS Federated View to calculate the data according to how I mentioned above and replace the `0` amount with the calculated amount for each row.
5. Store the result of these calculated transactions in a CSV file in AWS S3 and return the S3 URL.
6. Store the reference S3 URL somewhere (?) so that the calculations do not need to be run each time the data is queried, saving my money since AWS Athena charges per the number of bytes scanned per query.
7. Return the calculated data to the frontend for viewing.

Note:

Upon changes to the percentages in the two other tables that are required in order to do the calculation OR upon creation/deletion of a transaction, have AWS watch for these changes and automatically run the calculations again and replace the S3 file with a new one, thus replacing the URL reference as well.

Answer (score 0):

Financial statements are full of fluff and other stuff that you don't need.  Write an app to extract the desired numbers from the statements.

Put the numbers in table(s) that are structured for the coming steps.  Toss the rest of the stuff (or save it like you might save a picture -- just a big blob that has no particular structure).

Those raw numbers go into a database (MySQL / Aurora / whatever).  The Primary Key will include (at least) the company_id (linked to a table of companies), and year.

If needed, build summary tables that extract subtotals, differences, whatever, from those raw numbers.

*Then* write "reports" that display company comparisons, year-over-year comparisons, whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is one of the initial solutions I thought of in a way. But my reason for not doing this is because each statement has potentially thousands of items to get the sums of. So, I could extract them but then I'd need to store them in the DB  and that would cause the DB table to grow very large very fast. Also, the statements are royalties statements, so in order to provide useful insight, I do need much of the information in each statement, which is not fluff.

Comment: A billion rows is not impossible.  What is your estimate of the dataset size?